# How to change the header column's DisplayName and font of listviewwebpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm not able to change the column header in my XsltListViewWebPart. I have modified view and added the display name property. But its not working! How can I change the text, font etc of my header row in an XsltListViewWebPart ?

EDIT

I have added the displayname property to the View in my XsltListViewWePart. See the below part.

```
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Access" DisplayName="User level"/>
<FieldRef Name="Created" DisplayName="Date" />
<FieldRef Name="Modified" DisplayName="Last modified date" />
</ViewFields>
```

Comment: show us the code that is not working

Comment: I have added the changed view portion. Please check my updated question.